# Trying to get the content of an li using .each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have the following **HTML**

```
<ul id="masInfoPanel" data-role="listview" class="menu17 ui-listview">
    <li class="ui-first-child"> <a href="" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r">
        Mis Ventas    </a> 
    </li>
    <li class="current">    <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r">
        Mis Rentas    </a> 
    </li>
    <li>    <a href="" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r">
        Mis Búsquedas    </a>

    </li>
    <li>    <a href="" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r">
        Nuevo Anuncio    </a>

    </li>
    <li>    <a href="" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r">
        Mi Cuenta    </a>

    </li>
    <li>    <a href="" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r">
        Directorio de Solicitantes    </a>

    </li>
    <li data-icon="delete" class="ui-last-child"><a href="#" data-transition="slideup" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-delete">Cerrar menu</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div id="AddContent"></div>
```

I am trying to get the text inside `anchor` tag but not able to do that

The script I have is like this

**JS**

```
 <script>
$(document).on('pagecreate',function(){
    $(document).on('vclick','#masInfoPanel',function(){
        $(this).find('li').each(function(){

        var cure = $(this).hasClass('current');
        if(cure){
            var text = $(this).text();
                $('#AddContent').html(text);

        }

        });
    });

});

</script>
```

What I am trying to do is when I click on any `li` then the text of 'li' that has `current` class should get added to div `AddContent`.

Here is a UPDATED [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Vicky_Anand/78jGL/2/)

Thanks

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy - Virtual click: http://api.jquerymobile.com/vclick/

Comment: I could not able to find element which is having id `masInfoPanel` ..?

Comment: Your question is ambiguous: *"..I am trying to get the text inside `anchor` tag.."* and then you say *"..then the text of `li` that has current class should get added.."* ?

Comment: I am updating the question sorry . please give me some time

Comment: I am waiting for your update

Comment: @Sudharsan I am also waiting...

Comment: @Sudharsan  I am also waiting..

Comment: please create a fiddle and share the link in the question: jsfiddle.net

Comment: I have updated the fiddle . Please have a look

Comment: masInfoPanel id is not in the fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$(document).on('vclick', 'ul.menu17', function (e) {

    $(this).find('li').each(function () {

        if ($(this).hasClass('current')) {
            var text = $(this).text();
            $('#AddContent').html(text);

        }

    });
});
```

### OR

```
 $(document).on('vclick', 'ul.menu17 li.current', function (e) {
       $('#AddContent').html( $(this).text());
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/78jGL/6/)

Comment: I am not sure but My page has other <Ul > too with different id's so maybe ul selector will confuse things . Just my opinion I am very new to Jquery :) . That was reason I was suing Id as selector

Comment: use class for that like "ul.menu17"

Comment: In your code there is no **id masInfoPanel**.that is why i used ul .now i changed to class

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Vicky_Anand/78jGL/7/   here is the fiddle this is what I wanted actually :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57132/discussion-between-vikram-and-bala).

Answer (score 1):

**Working Fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/n548T/1/**

Your HTML:

```
<ul data-role="listview" class="menu17 ui-listview">
    <li class="ui-first-child"> <a href="" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r">
        Mis Ventas    </a> 
    </li>
    <li class="current"> <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r">
        Mis Rentas    </a> 
    </li>
    <li> <a href="" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r">
        Mis Búsquedas    </a>

    </li>
    <li> <a href="" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r">
        Nuevo Anuncio    </a>

    </li>
    <li> <a href="" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r">
        Mi Cuenta    </a>

    </li>
    <!--<li>
    <a href="">
        <b>Mis Banners</b>
    </a>
</li>-->
    <!---- <li>
    <a href="">
        <b>Solicitudes de información</b>
    </a>
</li>--->
    <li> <a href="" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r">
        Directorio de Solicitantes    </a>

    </li>
    <li data-icon="delete" class="ui-last-child"><a href="#" data-transition="slideup" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-delete">Cerrar menu</a>

    </li>
</ul>
<div id="AddContent"></div>
```

Some jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("li").each(function (index, el) {
        $(this).click(function (event) {
            var cure = $(this).hasClass('current');
            if (cure) {
                $("#AddContent").empty();
                var text = $(this).text();
                $("#AddContent").append(text);
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Bro thanks I am trying to implement this with the JQM function will accept your answer when I am done :)

Comment: @Rishi I think Bala's answer was more precise so I accepted his . Thanks for the help though :) hope its kool! with ya

Comment: Not that I think my answer is perfect, but binding the event to your document and then looping through all `li`'s to find one with the class `current` is kind of redundant. If I reduce your problem to something easy, what you want to do is just check if an `li` with class `current` was clicked. So looping is just not performant enough.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work for the problem you have:

```
$('li.current').on('click', function() {
    var text = $(this).find('a').html();
    $('#AddContent').append(text);
});
```

JSFiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/78jGL/4/

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer

based on different people's opinion

JS.

```
$(document).on('vclick', 'ul.menu17', function () {
        $(this).find('li').each(function () {

            var cure = $(this).hasClass('current');
            if (cure) {
                var text = $(this).text();
                $('#AddContent').html(text);
            }

        });
    });
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Vicky_Anand/78jGL/7/)